# Speeding up web development

Tags: html

**Situation**

I have been working on a project lately where the UI development seems to be way too time consuming.  In this case, the "Business Rules" on the server-side are much more complicated than the presentation aspects as far as a Computer Science or complexity perspective.

I've found myself scratching/banging my head against the wall with problems with behaviour that differs from the intuitive approach all the way to being a black hole of time waste and poor documentation, where I might be trying to get a simple UI element to line up correctly.

I'm not complaining; I understand there are complexities and a wide audience to support with web development, but I am perplexed by how long it takes to do what seems should be the easy part compared to how long it takes to write the code with complex logic, math, science, etc.

**Question**

What are you thoughts and personal experience to go from concept to reality with web development and to do this rapidly, or at least in a way that you can have a sense of how long it might take?  I have purposefully not mentioned any frameworks or languages, because I would really like to here what web development stacks you use, what tools or best practices help you get things done faster, and how you end up with code that doesn't feel totally brittle and full of hacks.

Hyperbole, language preferences, and all thoughts welcome, I would at least like to get a sense of what is being used for web development that has a high success rate, even if it isn't the latest and greatest thing around.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I personally have found breaking everything up into small tasks helps.

The way I like to design web pages:

1. Draw out the design, or photoshop it.
2. Create the HTML - no CSS, no styling at all
3. Now add in your style - basic style, like positioning, save making the menu perfect for later
4. Connect to database if needed / server side code
5. Now add in any javascript, ajax needed
6. Tweak it to perfection

If you have all this broken into small tasks, when you get done with each, you feel more motivated to continue working.

Like I said, this is how I do it, and it seems to go quickly, especially since I only get about 1 to 2 hours a night to work.

Comment: I personally prefer to add AJAX in absolutely last as it can turn things into a mess and make things difficult to change.

Comment: Could you possibly elaborate or mention how you would tie in server-side code development?  Many languages allow you to embed HTML and server code together, but this makes things difficult for obvious reasons (if not, that's another discussion).  At what phase do you write and tie in the back end code?

Comment: I always add styling in last. I only add very little styles because I am always working on making the functionality more featureful. I only add CSS when it gets way too out of hand and unpleasant to the eye.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this question depends on if you are working alone or leading a group.

If you are leading a group you will want to break apart responsibilities as the following:

- Designers - These people should own the creation of graphical mockups and the creation/maintenance of CSS.  They should own CSS as a responsibility so that they know not to create outrageous graphical mockups that cannot be created as a webpage without considerable code bloat.
- Markup - These people should own the authoring of HTML, accessibility, semantics, RDFa requirements, and any other aspect associated with front end data structure.
- UIT - These people should own JavaScript, efficiency requirements, content-management requirements, internal process and front-end tool/process governance, and generally own best practices for all client visible code.
- Applications - These people should own server-side application code development, content management system creation/maintenance, and database access requirements.  These people are application and services programmers and provide the interface to database and services personnel.
- QA - These people test all business requirements of the final product in a certification environment.  If errors are seen the bug/ticket should be updated and reassigned.  The work is not finished until QA signs off as valid.
- Business Owner - The business owner is the person/team responsible for writing the initial project requirements and making a final approving decision about the deployment of the project.  This person should have no interface to the technology process outside the drafting of business requirements.
- Project Manager - This person ensures that a project is continually moving forward and that milestones are completed in accordance with any deadlines.  It is this person and not the business owner that is to interfere with the technology process to ensure things are getting done.  This person must act independently of the business owner and must not serve as a tool to the business.  The project manager must not own or recommend changes to the requirements to the technology personnel.  If changes to the requirements must be made this is a one way process from technology through the project manager to the business owner.
- The flow of development should be the following:

  1) Designers create the graphic mockup and then reassign the bug/project ticket to the project business owner.

  2) Upon business approval the ticket should be reassigned to Markup staff or rejected back to design with specific change requests.

  3) Markup writes the HTML and content.  Any application or database requirements should be specified by business before the project begins and the Markup team should write code for all possible scenarios.  The structure of content should reflect the organization of content on the visual markup completely without regard for presentation.  The ticket should be reassigned back to Design for CSS creation.

  4) Design writes the CSS to add presentation in compliance with the graphical mockup they created.  The design team must have access to the HTML markup to add class attributes as necessary, but should not be allowed to make any other changes.  The ticket should be reassigned to Applications to complete all server side requirements.

  5) Applications should create all necessary requirements for database access.  Ticket should be reassigned to UIT if the prior requirements are satisfactory or reassigned back to Markup for changes/additions.

  6) UIT should be the final step to write the JavaScript interactions necessary for user-interface and AJAX requirements.  UIT also should proof the prior completed markup for standards conformance, efficiency, and best practices.  UIT should quickly reject the project if the work is less the acceptable.  If additional Applications work is required reassign to Applications otherwise reassign ticket to QA.

  7) QA is the final technology stop.  These people test the business and functional requirements of the final product.  The project cannot be released to production without QA sign off.  If a business requirement fails QA must not sign off.  Upon QA sign off the ticket should be reassigned to the business owner.

  8) The business owner reviews the project and determines if all requirements are achieved.  If changes/additions are required they can be submitted at this time.  Changes/additions MUST NOT be submitted earlier, because frequent changes delays all projects.  It is the responsibility of the business owner to ensure their initial requirements are complete and specific.  If the requirements are not reviewed for fullness it is the fault of the business owner and changes can be submitted at this point.  It is because of this responsibility, and other associated business responsibilities, that the business owner deserves to get paid more for being less involved.

That is the most efficient manner to get the job done.  Separation of duties is extremely important and adherence to the process is extremely important.  If those two things fail the entire process fails and business incurs significantly increased development costs.

If you are acting on your own and not part of a team I would still follow a similar process and push the role business owner onto the client.  If the client wants to make changes/additions premature to the project completion then they can pay more money by amending a change addendum to the original requirements contract.  You do not loose pay from increased labor because a client cannot make up their damn mind.  If that is upsetting then the client can pay even more money for a contract cancellation.  This is not mean it is business.  If your time is not a valued commodity then you should not be in business as on your own.

Comment: You have analyzed the process and the problems of every step fairly well. But you are not proposing any solutions. Remember main goal is to have computers work for people not the other way around. With that said I would love to hear ideas to automate and optimize every step of this process in order to achieve rapid development.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using the .NET stack for about 5 years, the ASP.NET MVC stack for about 3 months, and old ASP for 4 about years.

The key to dealing with complexity is mitigating it.  In your code, always abstract away complexity to a reasonable level.  For example, say there are 10 steps to placing an order.  In that case, at a higher level, you would have a method 'SubmitOrder'; under it might be 10 method calls for inserting appropriate records, dealing with inventory and so on.   In each of those 'business' layers, you can just deal with these business problem, and even below those layers, you would deal with data and mechanical details.  The benefit to all of these layers is that you make each layer deal with a chunk of the work, and as you go up closer to the UI, you have an 'interface' that makes sense to the UI and the way the application needs to flow.

Comment: Your first paragraph is confusing.  Please don't tell me you are using MVC as a hammer.  MVC is not supposed to be used when you need things like ViewState and Postback, so it would make sense to not use Telerik controls with MVC.

Comment: Just a comment about that you should not use MVC if you are using 'postback controls'.  Will edit later.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're a little mistaken about UI development. UI development is difficult and usually underestimated in its importance.

There's a need to know the basics - before you jump to HAML, know your HTML so you know what you're abstracting away. Before you jump into jQuery take the time to learn JavaScript basics - you don't need to be a pro, but when you need to add some numbers together you should **not** go looking for a plugin. Have a good understanding about how to style things with CSS. There's a lot to topics and technologies to learn to be a competent web UI dev.

That said, for greenfield development Rails is pretty sweet. Pick jQuery. And don't choose a platform that hides how the web really works.

Answer (score 0):

I use UI designers. They are excellent for that sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

I craft my application requirements around what is practical and sometimes easy in terms of front-end work.

Answer (score 0):

My companies does mostly .NET development and we have been successfully using the 'net-tiers' templates for data access layer. The templates are loaded into CodeSmith code generator and pointed against a database. The end result is anything you could possibly think of. It'll generate your DAL, webservice, winforms UI library, web UI library, a sample website and administration tool and more. A great tool to save some development time. Check it out.

As far as actually working on UI, i think it may benefit to actually hire a professional. We have a professional designer who does some contract work with us. All that we do is wire up the UI to our UI components and code.

Answer (score 0):

To speed up getting an HTML page that looks like you want:

First, decide on a design and draw what you want it to look like using a graphics program (if you've got a UI designer they do this step). Then, write static HTML and CSS that matches what you've drawn. Once that's done, write code that outputs HTML that matches the format that you've decided on.

I did this for a pretty complex set of states for a web app, and found that first writing HTML and CSS by hand, without having to wrestle with your server program, makes it go much faster.

Answer (score 0):

The common mistake web developers do most often is that they start writing markup without thinking what they are making and How it will look like. Later when they stuck in any problem then they have to restructure the markup several times which also affect the design too and not an efficient way.

Good developers have habit to design first then develop. What I mean to is it is better to design your website in Photoshop first the start coding. This help them a lot because they knew what they are making and what they can do later as well.

After planning let's talk something about the coding environment. Of we have a nice setup for web development then it will increase our productivity. The major part is Text Editor .It is very important to have a nice Text Editor because we do most of our work on Text Editor. Text Editor plays an important role in increasing our productivity. Well,You can't use notepad or notepad++ in 2019 . They are outdated. The best Editor in 2019 is VSCODE and Sublime Text.

Personally I use sublime Text with some plugins.

Another important part of web development is version control. You can use `git` for this purpose. There are many online free cloud storages too like `github` , `bitbucket` etc. on which we can save our code and access it from any part of the world. Now these days many people are remote workers and to share their work they use `git`. It is not only helpful in web development but it is also helpful in every software industry. This also allow you to try different styles by simply making branches without messing up with the code.

The least famous but most important part of any software developer or web developer is to use comments while coding because on small project it is very easy to find a particular piece of code but when you are working on large projects or work with a team then comments are necessary because the other developer might not be familiar with your naming conventions. If we use comments then you know what this particular code do.

In last one more thing I would like to suggest for web development is to use browser's developers tool. They are truly awesome and very helpful in finding an error. Developers tools contain console, live code preview, responsive website preview with various mobile devices options and much more.

Some useful plugins for web development are:

1. Emmet
2. Prettify
3. Color Picker
4. File Icon
5. Git gutter
6. Integrated Terminal

Hope you get the answer of your question

Answer (score 0):

Developers are extremely prolific individuals. They are continually improving their tools in order to increase their production and produce better outcomes faster.

For over a decade, I've been doing full-stack web development. One of the most difficult hurdles I'm having right now is that I need to focus on a range of tasks in a short amount of time, from designing user interfaces to deploying web applications.

**To speed up my outpu**t, I use a number of technologies and frameworks. For UI, I usually use Bootstrap 4 and Bulma for most of my projects when it comes to building responsive web apps.

As I continue to focus on developing a variety of Web applications, I've seen that there are certain similar themes that I've noticed when doing so:

**Consider the following example:**

1. User Interface for Login/Signup/Forget Password
2. Layouts like a dashboard
3. Layouts for User Profiles
4. Form of Configuration
5. The list could go on and on.

I believe that most full-stack developers have come across the same UI pattern when developing their Web Apps UI.
So, to make the above procedure go faster, we created a simple tool that allows you to drag and drop — pre-made Bootstrap 4 components like Signup Form with Cover Image, Login Form, Dashboard Layout, and so on...
But wait, there are already a number of comparable Bootstrap builders out there, so why do I need to create another one?

The majority of Bootstrap Builders are focused on creating websites, however we choose to create this specifically for Creating Faster Web Apps UI.

**Other aspects have also been taken into account.**

Because drag and drop is sometimes a limiting choice for developers to modify the layout, we created an in-built full-featured Code Editor that allows you to generate numerous HTML, CSS, and JS files to extend the UI of your Web Apps.

In conclusion, you may make use of the following advantages.

- Drag & Drop — Pre-Made Bootstrap Blocks — Dashboard Layouts, Signup
  Forms, *Login Forms, E-Commerce Order Layouts, and more
- Drag and Drop — Default Bootstrap Components to improve the layout
  even more, such as Buttons, Cards, and so on...
- Create/Edit UI enhancements using HTML, CSS, and JS.
- Use the entire project for production or future development by
  downloading it.
- Publish to Netlify to show off your work to potential clients.

I hope, you enjoy using this tool for creating responsive Web Apps UI faster.